# Alternate for getting the product id instead of registry()

Tags: magento2, registry

Unable to get the registry for current product by selecting the product in magento 2.

Im trying to update the product id of the product which gets deleted from below code during the delete event `catalog_product_delete_after`:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productdel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');  
$productid=$productdel->getEntityId(); 
 ....
```

I get `getEntityId()` on null.

I m just selecting the checkbox of the product to be deleted in backend and i guess its not able to get the `productid` in the current registry.

**`OTHER CASE:`**

The above works if i try to update any product attribute.