# Alternate method of getting product_id without using registry()

Tags: magento2, registry

How to get the current product id.

I don't want to get the product information from id (I want to get only the current id dynamically, not by assigning some value and get through object manager).

Currently I have used something like:

Event.xml

```
<event name="catalog_product_delete_after">
    <observer name="catalog_product_delete_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncProductDeleteObserver"/>
</event>
```

Observer:

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $productdel = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $this->productDelete($productdel);
    return $this;

}

public function productDelete($productdel)
{
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productdel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');  
    $productid=$productdel->getEntityId(); 
  ....
```

ERROR:

**I get getEntityid() on null during product delete.**

I want to use an alternative to `registry()`.

Please provide any other method?

Answer (score 1):

you can inject an instace of the registry class in your class.

```
class myClass
{
    protected $registry;
    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ....
    )
    {
        ....
        $this->registry = $registry;
        ...
    }
}
```

then you can use this inside your class.

```
$product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
```

Comment: I tried that method...but during product delete event current product id is not getting captured in registry...I face issue like this  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132624/alternate-for-getting-the-product-id-instead-of-registry

Comment: So i wanted to know if there is any alternate to registry method

Comment: then you should use an event for before delete, or a plugin for that.

Comment: I m using catalog_product_delete_after event and in my observer i say:  $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $productdel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product'); $productid=$productdel->getEntityId();

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Any alternate @Marius?

Comment: I already answered your question, and gave you 2 alternatives. I don't know what more do you want. Maybe you should rephrase your question to explain your problem not your approach.

Comment: Problem right now is if i use registry() and try to get the id, i get the error as highlighted...Please tell how to use beforeDelete or plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin for this. Declare plugins in your module's di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="acme_foo_catalog_product_plugin" type="Acme\Foo\Plugin\Catalog\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

Then create the plugin class at `app/code/Acme/Foo/Plugin/Catalog/ProductPlugin.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Foo\Plugin\Catalog;

class ProductPlugin {

    public function afterDelete(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $result) {
        // do something with $product->getId();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Read more about how plugins work at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html